# Using group_map to create multiple plots: fill color by each group?

Tags: r

I am trying to create plots for each level of a grouping variable, but I would like for each of the plots to use a different fill color (based on the grouping variable).

It's easy enough to use group_map to produce a list of the three plots that correspond to the three levels of `cyl`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  group_map(
    .f = ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
      geom_point()
  )
```

But I can't figure out how to make the fill color vary based on the level of `cyl`.

My initial inclination was to use `fill = .x$cyl`, but this (a) does not work, and (b) produces warnings about "Unknown or uninitialized column: cyl" and that "use of .x$cyl is discouraged":

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  group_map(
    .f = ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = .x$cyl)) +
      geom_point(size= 10)
  )
```

I also tried doing something with `cur_group_id()`, but this always returns a group id of 1, so the colors don't change per plot.  (`cur_group_id()` only works inside dplyr verbs, so I wrapped it in this mutate first):

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  group_map(
    .f = ~ mutate(.x, dotcolor = cur_group_id()) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = dotcolor)) +
      geom_point(size= 10)
  )
```

Any help would be appreciated: I have now spent (way) more time trying to figure this out than it would have taken to just create each of the plots individually :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question; I think this is a potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_map(
    .f = ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = factor(.y$cyl))) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("4" = "purple", "6" = "firebrick3", "8" = "deepskyblue"))
  )
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: This does indeed do it!  In an ideal world, it wouldn't require a manual color scale. In my case there are only 3 levels of the grouping variable, but in a more general application with more groups, manually specifying the scale could be a bit of a pain.  But this works for what I need now!